# Rightmost occurrence string match in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string

I would like to extract the file extension from a field in MySQL that contains filenames. This means I need to find the final '.' character in the field and extract everything after that. The following code example partially works:

```
SELECT LCASE(RIGHT(filename, LENGTH(filename) - LOCATE('.', filename)))
  FROM mytable;
```

except that it falls down for cases where the file name contains more than one '.', where it extracts too much. In most programming languages I'd expect to find a function that gives me a rightmost match, but I can't find any such thing for MySQL, nor can I find any discussion from people who have had the same problem and found a workaround.

Comment: Tim, please move the accepted answer to Martin's recent answer.  My old answer is functional but obviously misguided!   Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is the [substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function - it does exactly what you are looking for:

```
SELECT substring_index(filename, '.', -1) FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**:
See Martin's answer, using `substring_index()`, with a negative count parameter is a MUCH better approach!
I'm downvoting myself (actually that's not possible...), upvoting Martin's answer;  ' wish I could pass the accepted answer to him...  Maybe OP will do that.

---

Original answer:
The following may do the trick  (ATN: length may be off by 1, also may want to deal with case of filename value without a dot character.

```
SELECT LCASE(RIGHT(filename, LOCATE('.', REVERSE(filename) ) ))
  FROM mytable;
```

Beware however that this type of post-facto parsing can be quite expensive (read slow), and you may consider extracting the file extension to a separate column, at load time.